# $\mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}) = \mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y))$ What's the name for this proposition? Or alternatively what's happening?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value, intuition, conditional-expectation

If there isn't a name for this like Doob-Dynkin-Brown-Markov Tower Lemma / Theorem, then at least what's going on here so that I can describe this proposition in words?

(I guess the ff is in probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$.)

> Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathcal{F}, X, Y$ be two random variables such that $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$ and $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, and let $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel-measurable function such that $\mathbb{E}(|\varphi(X, Y)|)<$ $+\infty$. Then
> $$
> \mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}) = \psi(Y) \quad \text { a.s., } \quad \text { where } \psi(y)=\mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, y)).
> $$

From here:

1. [If $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$ and $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, then $\mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}) = \mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4618546/if-x-is-independent-of-mathcalg-and-y-is-mathcalg-measurable-then)
2. [Why is Borel measurability needed here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4363359/why-is-borel-measurability-needed-here)
3. Example 4.1.7 of [Durrett PTE](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf)

Also I do recall it is in my class notes from before:

[image]

Comment: For some people it's the Freezing lemma. There does not seem to be consensus on it. See for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607972/do-you-know-this-result-about-conditional-expectation

Comment: @Will ok thanks. in this case what is 'frozen' here? $Y$? I mean like instead of 'tower rule' I can say 'in a double expectation, the smaller $\sigma-$algebra wins.' What about this?

Comment: Yes the thing frozen here is $Y$, because the expected value for a certain outcome $\omega$ is the same as if we computed it with $Y$ inside frozen equal to $y=Y(\omega)$. But that's just a point of view, which maybe does not make sense for everyone, which would explain why there is not a strong consensus on this lemma's name. For me it makes sense and I am happy to call this the freezing lemma.

Comment: @Will oh very nice. thanks. post as answer?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4618609/66096

Comment: the statement on the title is wrong, is not true that $\operatorname{E}[\varphi (X,Y)|\mathcal{G}]=\operatorname{E}[\varphi (X,Y)]$, what is true is that $\operatorname{E}[\varphi (X,Y)|\mathcal{G}](\omega )=\operatorname{E}[\varphi (X,Y(\omega ))]$ for almost every $\omega \in \Omega $

Comment: @Masacroso it's like how several youtube titles are 'wrong'. There isn't enough space? Or feel free to make an edit proposal.